# How to limit max upload file size for specific file type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with author. They always upload large images.

I want to set max size upload to 500Kb but only for image because they upload PDF larger than 500Kb

Example I want to set jpg|png max 500Kb and pdf|mp3 max 5Mb.

I try to search solution on many site but no hope.

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the browser or on the server but the methods are completely different (You might have to do both especially if JavaScript is disabled in the browser).

The HTML5 Rocks article describes how to use JavaScript and the FileReader object to get information about the file (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). This could be used to check the both the file extension and the file size and act appropriately.

On the web server side you need to check out the php manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php for everything about uploading files.

Be aware that the server is only aware of the extension and size after it has been fully uploaded to the server - wasting your uploaders time before producing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'll drop this answer here because Google makes this question a top result.

```
function my_max_image_size( $file ) {
  $size = $file['size'];
  $size = $size / 1024;
  $type = $file['type'];
  $is_image = strpos( $type, 'image' ) !== false;
  $limit = 750;
  $limit_output = '750kb';
  if ( $is_image && $size > $limit ) {
    $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output;
  }
  return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_max_image_size' );
```

[Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228300/set-limit-to-media-upload)